# Wireless card stopped working after kernel upgrade

Tags: wifi, drivers

So I upgraded to kernel 3.19.0, which went fine except that the wireless card stopped working. I would have searched for the driver for the wireless card, except that I'm on a laptop with no ethernet port, so if the wireless is gone, there's no internet.

I made a Timeshift backup before I started, and was able to restore my system to the pre-upgrade state, which is where I am now.

Anyone have some advice on how to make the wireless card work after upgrading? Or should I hold out until the next kernel upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, with some help from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3n0bjy/upgraded_to_kernel_3190_wireless_card_stopped/

I was using the following to clear enough space on /boot to do the upgrade:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

And when I did it again, I noticed that some of the things it was removing were dependencies for the package bcmwl-kernel-source, which handles the wireless card.

So I just installed bcmwl-kernel-source after running the above command, upgraded the kernel and it works, wifi and all!